# How showing vertex paint in object mode blender 2.8

Tags: vertex-paint

I want to show vertex paint in object mode in blender 2.80.

Answer (score 5):

When in Solid Shading Mode, go to the config panel found in the top right corner of the viewport and for color select Vertex Colors where probably Material is currently selected

Comment: hi thank for you answer,when previously i used  in blender 2.79 ther was in blender render under material panel in option section vertex color paint option tick option available, where that option in blener2.80  once again thank you